# Como verificar se uma id existe?

Tags: javascript

Esse script não tá funcionando, eu só quero que a variável thumb seja criada se o id thumb existir, se não existir o script segue. Parece que quando o thumb não existe dá erro e o script nem funciona. Obs: Eu to usando só o notepad++, não vejo mensagens de erro.

```
if(document.getElementeByid("thumb") !== null)
{
    var thumb = document.getElementeByid("thumb");
}
comandos;
```

Comment: Só avisando algo para uso futuro, quando quiser saber se algo existe ou não, compare com `undefined`, não com `null`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não existe função `getElementeByid` no JavaScript.

- não é "Elemente", é "Element"
- e o "Id" é com maiúscula.

Função correta: `getElementById`.

E não precisa chamar duas vezes a função, pode reaproveitar assim:

```
var thumb = document.getElementById("thumb");

if(thumb)
{
    // faz algo se o elemento existir
}
```

Ou ainda:

```
var thumb = document.getElementById("thumb")||(valor alternativo ou função se não existir);
```

Comment: Eu escrevi errado aqui mas na verdade eu to usando document.querySelector("#thumb").

Comment: querySelector pra ID não faz nenhum sentido. ID é pra ter um só por DOM, então a função adequada é `getElementById` de qualquer maneira.

Comment: Mas eu sempre uso querySelector e funciona.

Comment: "Funciona" não é o mesmo que ser adequado. Se for pra class, ou outra combinação, aí sim. De qq forma, o getElementById é mais eficaz sempre que puder.

Comment: De qualquer forma, usando o get ElementById corretamente funcionou. Valeu.

Answer (score 1):

Teste assim:

```
if($('#thumb')){
   //Se existir o id verdadeiro entra aqui
}else{
   //Se não existir entra aqui.
}
```

Comment: Só funciona se a pessoa estiver usando JQuery.

Comment: exato obg por avisar me esqueci deste detalhe, para usar sem jQuery troque por document.getElementById('thumb');